Wiz Vulnerabilitites on Windows Server
I am dealing with a very old .net application in 4.7 framework. The app is deployed on a Windows VM(EC2 instance) hosted in AWS. The devops release agent is on the same app server (self hosted). There is wiz vulnerability report that has been exported and I want to share some of the errors here and my understanding on them.

There are multiple occurrences of each of these and I am sharing a unique subset.
Now, my understanding on these issues is that a regular clean up of agent folder (manually or job), windows update should do? I am confused on some like Azure Identity and such packages do I need to update them in my code? If it is not asking a lot can anyone please suggest me on the line items in the image to help me decide my approach?
